# Populate textbox from database or label

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm having trouble figuring this out and it shouldn't be too difficult.  I want to populate my `textbox` from my database or from the `label` (The labels are pulling the information from the database already, so essentially copying what's in the label to the textbox).  I'm using a `GridView` and here is the code that I've been trying:

C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                TextBox timeR = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("rTime") as TextBox;
                Label timeRL = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("labelRunScore") as Label;
                if (timeR.Text == "")
                {
                    timeR.Text = timeRL.Text;

                }

            }
```

.aspx:

```
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText = "Run Time">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelRunScore" Visible="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("rTime") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Run Time">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <div style="display:none"> <asp:TextBox ID="rTime" runat="server" type="number" Text='<%# Eval("rTime") %>' ></asp:TextBox></div>
           <input onblur="document.getElementById('<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("rTime").ClientID %>').value = this.value" 
    type="number" style="width: 100px; height: 31px;" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to make sure that `timeRL` has a value?

Comment: Well if `timeRL` does not have a value then couldn't we copy that null value into the Textbox.  Would that work?

Comment: If there's no value in `timeRL`, then the textbox would remain empty.

Comment: I just added another Textbox and see if it would copy the label and it did.  I think the issue is this code `<div style="display:none"> <asp:TextBox ID="rTime" runat="server" type="number" Text='<%# Eval("rTime") %>' ></asp:TextBox></div>
           <input onblur="document.getElementById('<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("rTime").ClientID %>').value = this.value" 
    type="number" style="width: 100px; height: 31px;" />
` It's placing the values into the `TextBox` not the `input`

Comment: Instead of writing `if (timeR.Text == "")` you should write `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(timeR.Text))`. However, what's the purpose of this check in this particular case? This make the code copy from label only if textbox was initially empty. Could You remove this `if` statement and check if this helps? Also, take note that `div` where the `TextBox` resides is hidden because of this code: `style="display:none"`.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, Thanks for the comment.  I need to keep the `display:none` because I'm using the `input` tag so it forces Keypads on Android OS and Apple OS.

Comment: Ok, i see. Please write what's happening when you execute your code (does some kind of error appear or text boxes are just empty). Please also write where (in what method) you call the c# snippet you've posted in the question.